# How to loop back to initial variable input in python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming, so bear with me. I want to create a program that combines whole numbers and fractions. It also displays their metric equivalents. While I am sure there is a better way to do this, I have done it as follows:

```
**from __future__ import division
w=int(input('Enter Whole Number: '))
fn=int(input('Enter Fraction Numerator: '))
fd=int(input('Enter Fraction Denominator: '))
print w+(fn/fd)," inches"
print (w+fn/fd)*25.4," mm"**
```

My question is how do I get the program to prompt the user with "Enter whole number:" every time he/she reaches the end of the program? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `while` loop:

```
**from __future__ import division
while True:                                 #Never ending
    w=int(input('Enter Whole Number: '))
    fn=int(input('Enter Fraction Numerator: '))
    fd=int(input('Enter Fraction Denominator: '))
    print w+(fn/fd)," inches"
    print (w+fn/fd)*25.4," mm"**
```

Or use a function and `while` loop:

```
**from __future__ import division
def Function():
    w=int(input('Enter Whole Number: '))
    fn=int(input('Enter Fraction Numerator: '))
    fd=int(input('Enter Fraction Denominator: '))
    print w+(fn/fd)," inches"
    print (w+fn/fd)*25.4," mm"**

while True:
    Function()
```

To quit, how about making the input equal to "QUIT" then quit the program or use `break` to stop the loop thus ending the program.